# updating Details View using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 Jquery and AJAX to produce something like List/Details view.

Now I have some code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
          alert('row was clicked');
          $('#Container').load('../task/create/').fadeIn("slow");

      });
  });
```

My HTML is as following

```
<table id="example" border = "2">
    <thead>
    <tr style="border-style:solid"  class="simplehighlight">
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            tblStatu
        </th>
        <th>
            DueDate
        </th>
        <th>
            AssignedTo
        </th>
        <th>
            CreatedOn
        </th>
        <th>
            CreatedBy
        </th>
        <th>
            ModifiedOn
        </th>
        <th>
            ModifiedBy
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr style="border-style:solid">
        <td style="border-style:solid">
            @item.Name

            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tblStatu.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedTo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedOn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedBy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TaskId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TaskId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TaskId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
   </tbody>
```

Now, How can I add parameter in my URL task/..... according to the selection if the row of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like (not tested) -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
          alert('row was clicked');
          var rowid = $(this).attr("id");
          $('#Container').load('../task/create/',{rowid: rowid}).fadeIn("slow");

      });
  });
```

That should use the [data] parameter of the load function to pass some data back to the url you are calling - the data will be POSTed back.

**EDIT**

Here's the final working code -

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $('#example tbody tr').click(function () { 
      var rowid = $(this).find('td#Name').html(); 
      //alert(rowid); // rowid = 1;
      $('#Container').load('../task/edit/' + $.trim(rowid)).fadeIn("slow"); 
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: I did not understand this part?                                  var rowid = $(this).attr("id");           $('#Container').load('../task/create/',{rowid: rowid}).fadeIn("slow");

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to comunicate to HTMl is through TD and TR at thsi moment so how attr("id") would be able to fetch any information from it?

Comment: That's supposed to be an example of what you could do. Get some data from the row (the row id in this example, but you could get whatever you need) then post that data back to the '../task/create/' URL.

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` should return the id attribute of the currently clicked row - providing the row has an id attribute. `$(this)` and `this` inside the 'click' function should contain a reference to the row that was clicked.

Comment: so How do I represent if I want some <TD id = "Name">'s innerHTMl for that row?

Comment: `$(this).html()` should get you the innerHTML for the row that was clicked.

Comment: I want HTMl for a particulat TD in that TR whose ID = name and I tried  (this).find("td:Name").HTML(). It does nto seem to work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3325/discussion-between-californicated-and-ipr101)

Comment: If the td looks like this `<td id="name">` then this should get the HTML `$(this).find("td#hame").html()`. `id`s should only appear in the document once though. Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hdxf9/

Comment: I'm in chat now if you're still keen to discuss

Comment: thank you so much for your help. For all the other reader. The problem was resolved in a chat session so I am posting th elatest code for everyone's reference

Comment: `code $(document).ready(function () { $('#example tbody tr').click(function () { var rowid = $(this).find('td#Name').html(); alert(rowid); // rowid = 1;` $('#Container').load('../task/edit/' + $.trim(rowid)).fadeIn("slow"); }); });`